# Why do I sometimes use stimpaks instead of my weapon during VATS?

Tags: fallout-4

I have noticed that sometimes in VATS mode when I try to fire my weapon, instead of firing, my character will use a stimpak and VATS will be cut off. Why does this occur and what can I do to control it?

Comment: There is an armor-ability that does that automatically, when you're below 20% health. Maybe it's that. I've never experoenced that bug myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on posts I'm finding, like [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/4a0u83/stimpack_in_vats_glitch/):

> Has anyone ever tried to attack in VATS and instead your character stabs himself with a Stimpack? This has happened to me several times, and today my character did it three times in a row until I gave up and manually shot the ghouls that were swarming me.

or [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3wdnto/vat_stimpak_glitch/):

> Hi all just wondering if anyone else is getting a glitch when entering executing a VAT and the character decides they need a stimpak more than killing the enemy. This started happening after I found the Deliverer and used it for the first time. I'll enter VAT and pick the locations but as soon as I try and execute my player will use a stimpak and then exit VAT... Been happening more and more, and the weird thing is that it doesn't use up any of my stimpaks in my inventory.

or [this one](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164593-fallout-4/72847727):

> Anybody have a problem with your character occasionally randomly using stimpaks in VATS?
>
> I unfavorited them but it still happens sometimes

It seems like this is just a very frustrating combat glitch, however, it doesn't seem to be listed on [this list of Fallout 4 bugs](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_bugs).

A possible fix is mentioned in the description of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rt3a_ZqiwU), which states:

> Switching in and out of 3rd person seemed to fix it, as you see at the end.